# how to implement pinch zoom in zoom out in js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement pinch zoom in zoom out in js.
I am almost there, as I have calculated how to detect pinch zoom in zoom out in js using touch events.

```js
var dist1=0;
function start(ev) {
if (ev.targetTouches.length == 2) {//check if two fingers touched screen
dist1 = Math.hypot( //get rough estimate of distance between two fingers
ev.touches[0].pageX - ev.touches[1].pageX,
ev.touches[0].pageY - ev.touches[1].pageY);
}

}
function move(ev) {
if (ev.targetTouches.length == 2 && ev.changedTouches.length == 2) {
// Check if the two target touches are the same ones that started
var dist2 = Math.hypot(//get rough estimate of new distance between fingers
ev.touches[0].pageX - ev.touches[1].pageX,
ev.touches[0].pageY - ev.touches[1].pageY);
//alert(dist);
if(dist1>dist2) {//if fingers are closer now than when they first touched screen, they are pinching
alert('zoom out');
}
if(dist1<dist2) {//if fingers are further apart than when they first touched the screen, they are making the zoomin gesture
alert('zoom in');
}
}

}
document.getElementById ('zoom_here').addEventListener ('touchstart', start, false);
document.getElementById('zoom_here').addEventListener('touchmove', move, false);
```

```html
<div class='zoom_here'></div>
```

now i want to translate the img as we keep zoom in

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add transform: scale();`

```js
var dist1=0;
function start(ev) {
if (ev.targetTouches.length == 2) {//check if two fingers touched screen
dist1 = Math.hypot( //get rough estimate of distance between two fingers
ev.touches[0].pageX - ev.touches[1].pageX,
ev.touches[0].pageY - ev.touches[1].pageY);
}

}
function move(ev) {
if (ev.targetTouches.length == 2 && ev.changedTouches.length == 2) {
// Check if the two target touches are the same ones that started
var dist2 = Math.hypot(//get rough estimate of new distance between fingers
ev.touches[0].pageX - ev.touches[1].pageX,
ev.touches[0].pageY - ev.touches[1].pageY);
//alert(dist);
if(dist1>dist2) {//if fingers are closer now than when they first touched screen, they are pinching
x/2
alert('zoom out');
img.style.transform = 'scale('+x+')'
}
if(dist1<dist2) {//if fingers are further apart than when they first touched the screen, they are making the zoomin gesture
2*x
alert('zoom in');
img.style.transform = 'scale('+x+')'
}
}

}
var x = 1
var img = document.getElementById ('zoom_here') 
document.getElementById ('zoom_here').addEventListener ('touchstart', start, false);
document.getElementById('zoom_here').addEventListener('touchmove', move, false);
```

`

Comment: and how to see only zoomed in part of the img for example img from mobile gallery we only zoom specific part of img

Comment: this is only  work for the img to zoom the img from center